# Insert header row for csv file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I tried to insert header row for csv file that contains 35M rows using the following segment of code

```
    import csv
    
    with open('E:\\Dataset\\dataset1.csv') as infile:
        text = infile.read()
    header = ['User IP','Top-level domain', 'Timestamp', 'Is Attack', 'Request',
                  'Len(request) withou TLD', 'Subdomains_count', 'w_count', 'w_max',
                  'entropy', 'w_max_ratio', 'w_count_ratio', 'digits_ratio', 'uppercase_ratio',
                  'time_avg', 'time_stdev', 'size_avg', 'size stdev', 'throughput', 'unique', 'entropy_avg'
                  'entropy_stdev']
    
    with open('E:\\Dataset\\dataset2.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        # join the headers into a string with commas and add a newline
        outfile.write(f"{','.join(header)}\n") 
        outfile.write(text)
```

However, when I tried to print data with the headerو the headers shifted one column.
this is the original head of data (without header)

```
   186.169.253.58     surbl.org  1624438272607  False  \
0  186.169.253.58     surbl.org  1624438272607  False   
1  186.169.253.58  spamhaus.org  1624438273058  False   
2  186.169.253.58  spamhaus.org  1624438273058  False   
3  186.169.253.58  spamhaus.org  1624438273059  False   
4  186.169.253.58  spamhaus.org  1624438273059  False   

                       h.surbl.org   1  1.1  0  0.1      -0.0       0.0  \
0                      f.surbl.org   1    1  0    0 -0.000000  0.000000   
1  118.141.11.106.sbl.spamhaus.org  18    5  0    0  2.633731  0.000000   
2  118.141.11.106.zen.spamhaus.org  18    5  1    3  2.633731  0.166667   
3  128.141.11.106.sbl.spamhaus.org  18    5  0    0  2.863826  0.000000   
4  128.141.11.106.zen.spamhaus.org  18    5  1    3  2.863826  0.166667   

      0.0.1     0.0.2  0.0.3  3.4444444444444446  9.59311095410544   1.5  \
0  0.000000  0.000000    0.0            0.222222          0.440959   1.0   
1  0.000000  0.611111    0.0           55.555556        165.542375  17.2   
2  0.055556  0.611111    0.0            0.333333          0.500000  17.2   
3  0.000000  0.611111    0.0            0.333333          0.500000  17.3   
4  0.055556  0.611111    0.0            0.333333          0.500000  17.4   

   1.5811388300841898        468.75  0.4444444444444444  0.25849625007211563  \
0            0.000000   3333.333333            0.555556             0.000000   
1            0.421637    343.313373            0.000000             3.048277   
2            0.421637  43000.000000            0.000000             2.983547   
3            0.483046  43250.000000            0.000000             2.959741   
4            0.516398  43500.000000            0.000000             2.935936   

   0.81743691684035  
0          0.000000  
1          0.177285  
2          0.199622  
3          0.198131  
4          0.193400
```

and this is the head of data after adding header

```
                     User IP  Top-level domain  Timestamp  \
186.169.253.58     surbl.org     1624438272607      False   
186.169.253.58     surbl.org     1624438272607      False   
186.169.253.58  spamhaus.org     1624438273058      False   
186.169.253.58  spamhaus.org     1624438273058      False   
186.169.253.58  spamhaus.org     1624438273059      False   

                                      Is Attack  Request  \
186.169.253.58                      h.surbl.org        1   
186.169.253.58                      f.surbl.org        1   
186.169.253.58  118.141.11.106.sbl.spamhaus.org       18   
186.169.253.58  118.141.11.106.zen.spamhaus.org       18   
186.169.253.58  128.141.11.106.sbl.spamhaus.org       18   

                Len(request) withou TLD  Subdomains_count  w_count     w_max  \
186.169.253.58                        1                 0        0 -0.000000   
186.169.253.58                        1                 0        0 -0.000000   
186.169.253.58                        5                 0        0  2.633731   
186.169.253.58                        5                 1        3  2.633731   
186.169.253.58                        5                 0        0  2.863826   

                 entropy  w_max_ratio  w_count_ratio  digits_ratio  \
186.169.253.58  0.000000     0.000000       0.000000           0.0   
186.169.253.58  0.000000     0.000000       0.000000           0.0   
186.169.253.58  0.000000     0.000000       0.611111           0.0   
186.169.253.58  0.166667     0.055556       0.611111           0.0   
186.169.253.58  0.000000     0.000000       0.611111           0.0   

                uppercase_ratio    time_avg  time_stdev  size_avg  \
186.169.253.58         3.444444    9.593111         1.5  1.581139   
186.169.253.58         0.222222    0.440959         1.0  0.000000   
186.169.253.58        55.555556  165.542375        17.2  0.421637   
186.169.253.58         0.333333    0.500000        17.2  0.421637   
186.169.253.58         0.333333    0.500000        17.3  0.483046   

                  size stdev  throughput    unique  entropy_avgentropy_stdev  
186.169.253.58    468.750000    0.444444  0.258496                  0.817437  
186.169.253.58   3333.333333    0.555556  0.000000                  0.000000  
186.169.253.58    343.313373    0.000000  3.048277                  0.177285  
186.169.253.58  43000.000000    0.000000  2.983547                  0.199622  
186.169.253.58  43250.000000    0.000000  2.959741                  0.198131
```

it looks like using the first column as index.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual CSV output to see if it wrote what you expected?

Comment: There is typo `'entropy_avg' 'entropy_stdev'` - missing `,` so python join last columns to `entropy_avgentropy_stdev`. solution is add comma like `'entropy_avg' ,'entropy_stdev'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to leverage it, use Pandas, as the header issues you're fighting are addressed by the explicit import and export flags available.

```
import pandas

header = ['User IP', 'Top-level domain', 'Timestamp', 'Is Attack', 'Request',
          'Len(request) withou TLD', 'Subdomains_count', 'w_count', 'w_max',
          'entropy', 'w_max_ratio', 'w_count_ratio', 'digits_ratio', 'uppercase_ratio',
          'time_avg', 'time_stdev', 'size_avg', 'size stdev', 'throughput', 'unique', 'entropy_avg',
                                                                                      'entropy_stdev']
pandas.read_csv('E:\\Dataset\\dataset1.csv', names=header, index_col=False)
pandas.to_csv('E:\\Dataset\\dataset2.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

It's unclear in your question if you *want* the indexes in the output, or if they were present in the input. If they're present in the input, set index_col=0. If you want them in the output, set index=True in the to_csv call.